Repeatable read behaviour
I was going through a course on udemy about databases. And there's some confusion about repeatable read isolation level. The lecture describes that if there are two transactions t1 and t2 and t1 fetches some data in repeatable read isoltaion level and then t2 inserts a new row and commits this new row is visible to t1 if the query is ran again ?
But from what i understand this is not the case and we will never see the new row inside t1, no matter how many times we run the query. I have used Postgres database.
-- Transaction t1 
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL repeatable read;
SELECT MAX(score) FROM scores;
 max
-----
 950
(1 row)

Now in other session i concurrently insert a new row with score 957.
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO scores(score) VALUES (957);
commit;

Now if i again go back in the t1 transaction which is not yet commited and i run the select query again.
SELECT MAX(score) FROM scores;

I get the same result 950, though a new row with value 957 is present and commited.
So what i understand is that repeatble read is kind of snapshot implementation which reads data upto the start time of transaction and which is commited. Am i right with this concept ?

I would say you either misunderstood the lecture, or the lecture was wrong.  The behavior described as being allowed is exactly what "repeatable read" avoids.

The video said that the repeatable read works when a row is updated so you will not see the updated value from the other transaction, but if a new row is inserted you will see it in your results !

Who cares about some video? Just check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

But there's no explicit mention for INSERT, under Repeatable Read.

There is: The Repeatable Read isolation level only sees data committed before the transaction began. INSERT and DELETE statements can also be committed. It's not limited to just UPDATE. Besides that, the Repeatable Read description would be really weird when a read is not repeatable.

Makes sense now! so what i can infer from this is Repeatable read is somewhat snapshot implementation atleast in Postgres ?

You understand correctly: REPEATABLE READ in PostgreSQL is snapshot isolation. You will see the same state of the database for the whole transaction, and if you try to modify a row that was concurrently modified after your snapshot was taken, you'll get a serialization error.
There has been scientific research about REPEATABLE READ, and there are many different possible variants of the concepts. Different database have different implementations of the concept. The root problem behind that is that the SQL standard's definition of REPEATABLE READ is sadly inadequate (for all their fastidiousness): all they have to say about it is that you cannot have “phantom reads” on that isolation level.
